# Variables/Functions in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure whether this kind of functionality exists or not or how is best to go about this. I am wanting to create a general problem solver where I can define the predicates, operations and such before solving rather than coding directly. So far I have been storing functions as part of a dictionary. The only way that it seems possible to do this with a dictionary is to create it with every potential combination imaginable.

For example, previously it was this:

```
    self.Operators = {"STACK": self.stack, "UNSTACK": self.unstack,
                      "PICKUP": self.pickup, "PUTDOWN": self.putdown}
```

Where I would now like it to be something more like:

```
self.Operators = {("STACK", x, y): [[("clear", y), ("holding", x)], ["armempty", ("on", x, y)]]}
```

I know I am probably barking up the wrong tree with dictionaries here but this is the first time I've tried to do something like this and I have no idea what the appropriate/most Pythonesque way to manage this is?

Comment: So far I've only tried:
Pre-parsing the dictionary entries to create all possible combinations in the problem space.
Attempting to create multiple lookup dictionaries to piece together a representation of the desired output.
That's about as far as I've gotten because I am still thinking in terms of dictionaries and I'm unaware of if there is anything else out there. I also considered a list comprehension but that didn't seem like it would be correct either.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the following (which is what I am going to go with):

```
self.Operators = {'PICKUP': [[['ontable', 'a'], ['armempty']], [['holding', 'a']]]}
```

The list that is then returned I parse using a list comprehension:

```
y = [w.replace("a", args[0]) for w in y]
```

For a list that has multiple variables, I will end up doing multiple list comprehensions by enumerating through characters.